# php sleep function, no other calls to webserver work until that original sleep finishes? how to bypass

Tags: php, multithreading, web, sleep

I have an api which a remote server calls, to execute set series of functions on our local server, ie adding new users / accounts.

Within this script, there is a 'sleep(180)' set to wait 3mins before emailing out a response to the remote server.

The delay is required, however we have found any requests after the 1st one to the server, do not seem to be getting processed, it is as if that 'sleep(180)' is halting other calls to the server.

Does it not work based on a connection basis? so every connection should only be affected not *every* remote call to that one api.php?

I have researched but not found an answer to the above behaviour, I'm guessing if that is the case, the only solution would be to record the incoming new account requests and put them into mysql in a 'scheduler' database table.. and perhaps have a cron that will run every 1-2mins and check for new records and then send out the response. This way there is no halting other calls.

I'd really appreciate any input on this matter as I can't seem to find anything proving/disproving whats happening.

Comment: There is no multithreading in php, you can fork out new processes but not run multiple processes on the same connection. perhaps you should add the requests to a que and then work through the job que with a separate process, work on dropping the sleep function out of your codebase.

Comment: Agree'd, thanks guys, I thought that'd be the best method / solution, but wasnt sure..

Answer (score 1):

As per 'Lawrence Cherone' comment, best method is to set up a scheduler/queuign system and have cron or another process work through it.